# Multiple Image Grouping Inside HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

does anyone have a reference related to grouping multiple images inside html canvas using JavaScript and j query only.
please note that i cannot use any libraries.

Comment: what do you mean "grouping multiple images" ?

Comment: i need to select multiple images by dragging and create a selection-box around them by clicking on the context-menu group option